# Angular 2+ / Typescript Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 7 and I am getting this data from a service:

```
{name: "peter", datetime: 1557996975991}
```

Then I have this method that gets the data:

```
myMethod() {

    this.myService.getdata().subscribe((res) => {

      console.log(res); // returns: {name: "peter", datetime: 1557996975991}

      console.log(res[0].datatime); // Gives Error: Cannot read property 'datetime' of undefined 

    }); 

}
```

When I try to get the datatime value I'm getting:

Gives Error: Cannot read property 'datetime' of undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are getting _datetime_. You are accessing _datatime_. What if you use `console.log(res.datetime)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The res variable is object not array.

You need change to `console.log(res.datatime);`

Change to

```
myMethod() {

    this.myService.getdata().subscribe((res: any) => {

      console.log(res); // returns: {name: "peter", datetime: 1557996975991}

      console.log(res.datatime);

    }); 

}
```

Comment: Can't do that as typescript said "Property datatime does not exist in object"

Comment: you should declare res: any

Comment: Even better is if you have an interface that represents {name: "peter", datetime: 1557996975991} so you can do like (res: IDataResource). I don't advise using 'any' in TS

Answer (score 1):

you r getting value from object use this

```
console.log(res.datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing your objects and arrays.

When you do `console.log(res[0].datatime)`, you're understanding the response as an array when you can clearly see it is an object here: `{name: "peter", datetime: 1557996975991}`.

As Hein pointed, you should access the `datatime` property with `console.log(res.datatime)`

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(res.datetime);` - note the `e` in `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @FailedUnitTest has said you the best way is declare an interface and in that way you can access to this values. Avoid use 'any' always because when the code gets harder and bigger maybe you could get into some troubles.